# How do I share contents of TextView from ViewPager?

Tags: java, android

I have ViewPager which takes 3 string array and sets array of content to 3 text views which are inflated in ViewPager. I am able to set text to TextView's. But, I want get and share content of perticular TextView's when I Long Press on it.

here's ViewPager Adapter

customSwipeAdapter.java

```
package com.regio.developers.upasana;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class customSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private String[] str1,str2,str3;
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public customSwipeAdapter(Context ctx,String[] str1,String[] str2,String[] str3){

    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.str1 = str1;
    this.str2 = str2;
    this.str3 = str3;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return str1.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout)object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences("UPASANA",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("PAGENUM",String.valueOf(position));
    editor.apply();

    //Log.d("Shared Pref adapter", "returned: " + position);

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.positiontextview1);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.positiontextview2);
    TextView textView3 = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.positiontextview3);
    TextView pagenum = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.pagenumtextview);
    textView1.setText(String.valueOf(str1[position]));
    textView2.setText(String.valueOf(str2[position]));
    textView3.setText(String.valueOf(str3[position]));


    pagenum.setText("" + (position+ 1) + "/" + str1.length);

    container.addView(item_view);

    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
}
}
```

Here ViewPager adapter takes three strings str1,str2,str3. It gives total of 69 Pages. I'm not using fragment but swipe layout to inflate the view. So, I want to share content of text view from only Visible ViewPager. Can you please help me? Thank You.

Comment: what do you mean by share

Comment: Share text using share intent like:
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                                "Hey check out my app at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus");
                        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        startActivity(sendIntent);

Comment: Try setting a `LongClickListener` on each of the text views and getting the value in the `onClick` method of the listener.

Comment: I tried to do that in simple way. But it retrieved data from other ViewPager, not from the page which is currently displayed

Comment: ok so you know how to do the share part , i don't understand what are you trying to share ? all the three textviews ?

Comment: No, only TextView's data which I clicked on

Comment: oh ok , and you tried longclicklistener on the textview , but it's giving you the text from a diffrent page ?

Comment: yes it returns text from other page. like 2 pages before's data

Comment: yes , that's caused by the offset of the viewpager , it loads more than one visible page , by default it loads one after and one before , so when it loads someone else it changes your textview and you get something else , you need to use fragment with it so it will do it correctly

Comment: Or if you don't want to do all that , you can save an int with the page you are on and get the texts you need not from the textview but from a hashmap or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to get the content of textview - 
Well, you can get the text from `TextView` iteself by using `textview.getText()` method.

Getting snippet from your code for the reference:-

```
textView2.setText(String.valueOf(str2[position]));
textView3.setText(String.valueOf(str3[position]));    
textView3.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                String str = textView3.getText().toString(); // use str to share
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I know that, but, what I want is to take content from text view which are from ViewPager. Where, in my case my ViewPager has 3 TextView's(3 text view's shown on screen). If I click on first TextView then take text from that only TextView not from other viewPager's.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It solved my problem. It was easy solution but I was not that smart to get that.